# How do I pass a List through the PreviousPage property?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, asp.net-3.5

I'm trying to pass some values to another page and I have the values in List (Of String). However, I'm getting an error (**at design-time in the IDE**) saying: There is no member "X" of System.Web.UI.Page. I was able to get the Property through Intellisense. So I'm not sure why I'm getting the error.

Here's the code:

```
'Source Page (Default.aspx)-

Private locationDetails As List(Of String)
    Public ReadOnly Property LocationsForDetail() As List(Of String)
        Get
            Return locationDetails
        End Get
    End Property

    Private loadDetails As List(Of String)
    Public ReadOnly Property LoadsForDetail() As List(Of String)
        Get
            Return loadDetails
        End Get
    End Property

    Private optionDetails As List(Of String)
    Public ReadOnly Property OptionsForDetail() As List(Of String)
        Get
            Return optionDetails
        End Get
    End Property

    Protected Sub RadButton2_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles RadButton2.Click

        For Each facility As ListItem In CheckBoxList1.Items
            If facility.Selected Then
                locationDetails.Add(facility.Text)
            End If
        Next

        For Each load As ListItem In CheckBoxList2.Items
            If load.Selected Then
                loadDetails.Add(load.Text)
            End If
        Next

        optionDetails.Add(DropDownList2.SelectedValue)
        optionDetails.Add(DropDownList3.SelectedValue)
        optionDetails.Add(DropDownList4.SelectedValue)
        optionDetails.Add(RadDatePicker1.SelectedDate.Value.ToShortDateString)
        optionDetails.Add(RadDatePicker2.SelectedDate.Value.ToShortDateString)

        Server.Transfer("Breakdown.aspx")
    End Sub


'Target Page (Breakdown.aspx) -

    Protected Sub populateChart()

        Dim locations As List(Of String) = PreviousPage.LocationsForDetail 'get error here
        Dim capacities As List(Of String) = PreviousPage.LoadsForDetail    'get error here
        Dim rescOptions As List(Of String) = PreviousPage.OptionsForDetail 'get error here

        bindData.populateChart(RadChart1, locations, capacities, rescOptions)
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Server.Transfer wouldn't do a postback to the page. I believe (however it's been a long time since I have used PreviousPage) that it only works when you the the PostBackURL property on a control.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that even though the IDE marked it as an error, the code compiled and ran fine. I'm not sure if I'm lucky, the IDE is buggy, or it's some sort of undefined behavior.